# What object differences would cause DataGrip MariaDB 10.3 driver to detect a change diff using schema comparison?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, phpstorm, datagrip

I am using the compare schema function in DataGrip for two databases in MariaDB, a dev and a production database, to perform a migration.

Upon pressing compare, I see several pre-selected columns that suggest that there is a difference between two columns in the schema of the two database tables. However, I cannot detect a difference.

In the following image, I see the types of the columns matching along with all the characteristics. But everything seems to match - name, non-null quality, etc.

Generally this function works correctly, but in this particular example, I'm unsure of what the difference is, why only two of the 20 or so columns are selected, and what else could cause there to be a diff.

The DDL diff even suggests they are the same:

```
create table beneficiaries
(
    id               int unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    user_id          int unsigned                                             not null,
    phone            varchar(191)                                             null,
    cellphone        varchar(191)                                             null,
    email            varchar(191)                                             null,
    deleted_at       timestamp                                                null,
    message_history  longtext collate utf8mb4_bin default '[]'                not null,
    activity_history longtext collate utf8mb4_bin default '[]'                not null,
    admin_id         int unsigned                                             null,
    created_at       timestamp                    default current_timestamp() not null,
    updated_at       timestamp                                                null on update current_timestamp()
)
    collate = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

[image: To me, the MariaDB table schema looks the same]

Comment: Could be the same issue as yours: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-15008. Also seem related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-11344

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed in the upcoming release 2022.1